# Download new uploaded file automatically in php without clicking any download button

Tags: php, mysql, download

I am working on a php project. I want to download every new uploaded file in mysql automatically without clicking any download link or button. I want that php script detect new uploaded file in mysql and download it automatically on hard drive .

How can I do that ?

Comment: please post some code here...

Comment: add the code to the question

Comment: Please update the question with the code, not in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of php upload script taken from php.net

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Now after echo you can return this

```
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

//Now here we will force the header to download the file as attachment in browser

return header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$uploadfile.'");
```

The upload script is just basic example, i posted it because you didn't show yours and i thought it will be better if you see it in action you can read more about headers here [PHP.NET - Headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: does this code will download new uploaded file automatically

Comment: Please show my complete post with code on following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059564/download-new-uploaded-file-automatically-in-php..  your suggested code download file when we upload file. but it is not fine. i have to download file on another machine. for example  user1 upload and user2 or user3 can download file on another machine.

Comment: Look mate... With all my respect but i think tou are still newbie to achieve this with php. Now there is a way to do it with php but it will be a

Comment: It will be overkill for you or you and your client ! Nobody is gonna do it for you without any code from you ! If u want the easy money if there are any you have to read a lot and when i mean a lot i mean F*****G Alot man. Now on the question Python will be capable of doing this without too many problems :) I Wish you good luck with this. P.S My answer based on your question is correct so please...